# How do I stop BitBake progress logging?

Tags: logging, bitbake

One might expect that the `-s` (`--silent`) option to bitbake would get rid of all the progress reports.  But I still get thousands of these lines:

```
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (657 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
[36A[JRunning tasks (658 of 2070)  31% ||
```

`$TERM` is `dumb`, so there really shouldn't be all those `^[` sequences in there, either.  I don't want this crap filling up my build logs; what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that I was running in a Docker container, and `$TERM` wasn't explicitly passed.  Then Bitbake was making incorrect guess.

The fix was easy: pass `-e TERM=${TERM:-dumb}` in the `docker run` command.